# Multiple HttpWebRequests to localhost eventually all cause Request timed out

Tags: asp.net, iis

We just deployed an application to a production server and we're have an issue with 2 components that use HttpWebRequest to scan its own pages on localhost.

Essentially, we are making a series of HttpWebRequests to localhost (using the domain name). They will work initially but eventually they all result in 'Request has timed out.' Once the component is restarted it will work for a bit then stop.

This wasn't a problem on our development environment. We've tinkered with multiple configs related to max connections and throttling but have so far come up blank.

EDIT: It's also important to note that the requests that time out never show up in the IIS logs.